# How to correctly cover all golang packages with all tests?

Tags: go, code-coverage, go-testing

Assume that some code defined under package `pkg/somepkg1`.
And there are some tests in this package and some tests are in package `tests/integration`.

If i call

```bash
go test -cover -coverprofile=cover.out ./...
```

i have got all tests run (including `integration`) but there is no cover information in `cover.out` - just coverage from `somepkg1` only! For example 78%

If i call

```bash
go test -cover -coverpkg=./pkg/somepackage1 -coverprofile=cover.out ./...
```

i have got exactly what i want - i see really all coverage for code is somepackage1 netherless it is from it's package or from `integration`. For example 85%.

So if want to check all packages in `./pkg` i call same code for all packages and then merge answers in one batch.  It takes long time and not good for CI

It's not consistent for me at all. I understand that fairy unit-tests are better than coverage thorough other modules and integration tests, but it's not friendly to use.

Is there way to cover all with all tests without calling such snippet against each package?

Comment: `go test -cover -coverpkg=./go/pkg/expr -coverprofile=cover.out ./... && cat cover.out | grep "pkg/expr" | wc -l   `  -> 17920 records

`go test -cover  -coverprofile=cover.out ./... && cat cover.out | grep "pkg/expr" | wc -l   `  -> 1280 records

Answer (score 1):

Use to test all packages indiscriminately:

```
 go test ./...
```

For all packages, you can add coverage as:

```
go test --cover ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
```

To test within a specific package would be:

```
go test --cover -coverpkg=./pkg ./pkg -coverprofile=cover.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```bash
go test -cover -coverpkg=./pkg/... -coverprofile=cover.out ./...
```

in this case - it do exactly what i want and it's not same as

```bash
go test -cover -coverprofile=cover.out ./...
```

if you want to test group of packages you can do it with

```bash
go test -cover -coverpkg=./pkg/pkg1,./pkg/pkg2 -coverprofile=cover.out ./...
```

with commas and no spaces